# How to programmatically deploy a stub on parasoft soaTest

Tags: jython, soa, stub, parasoft

I use a parasoft SoaTest 9.7 to create a stub simulator that I should deploy on Soa Server each time I want to run the Test cases.

So I want to know, is there any solution to automate the deployment of the stub on the Soa Server with a jython script or java class ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no such solution in SOAtest 9.7.
You should migrate to Virtualize 9.10 to get access to API which allows such automation.
Check Parasoft Virtualize Community Edition